# Get systemd service memory usage to store in bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I enabled some Accounting features in systemd daemob:

```
DefaultCPUAccounting=yes
DefaultIOAccounting=yes
DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes
DefaultTasksAccounting=yes
```

Now I can see, for example, the service memory usage:

```
● supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-21 15:10:05 UTC; 17min ago
       Docs: http://supervisord.org
   Main PID: 1842113 (supervisord)
      Tasks: 886 (limit: 108515)
     Memory: 31.9G
```

How can I get the "31.9G" value?

I can parse the text, of course, but I want to know if there is any systemd command to get that value that will simplify the bash parse.

I found this command:

```
root@panel:~# systemctl show supervisor | egrep -i memorycurrent
MemoryCurrent=34285473792
```

a
Probably is the best command to check that. I just want to check if someone has something better. I want to use systemd because I need to understand the memory used by the daemon and the threads.

Comment: You can use the `-p` flag with `systemctl show` to show a specific property. For example: `systemctl show -p MemoryCurrent supervisor`. No difference in the output, just another way of narrowing the results down without using another command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a systemd solution that is compatible with dbus, you can:

```
$ busctl introspect \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
   /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/supervisor_2eservice \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service
```

This will give you a list of all Service properties of your service.  When you know what property is interesting, you can simplify your command and ask for that specific property:

```
$ busctl get-property \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
   /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/supervisor_2eservice \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service \
   MemoryCurrent
```

This will return the following to stdout:

```
t 34285473792
```

The preceding `t` is the [type-specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#type-system).  It says that this is a UINT64.

If you want to "parse" it you could pipe that into `awk` or use `-j` to get `json` data and pipe that into `jq`:

```
$ busctl get-property \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
   /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/supervisor_2eservice \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service \
   MemoryCurrent | awk '{print $2}'
34285473792

$ busctl get-property \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
   /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/supervisor_2eservice \
   org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service \
   MemoryCurrent -j | jq '.data'
34285473792
```

---

The `org.freedesktop.systemd.Unit` interface may be more appropriate if you are looking for things like active status or dependencies, but I think the specific information you described here is only found on the `org.freedesktop.systemd.Service` interface.

The `dbus` interface is a nice low-level interface with `systemd`.  If you ever wanted to code something up in C, you'll be interfacing with `systemd` using this same interface (same service, object, interface, and property listed here)